# How do I set a Javascript variable to a Model string array in MVC3?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Model.Choices is a string array in my MVC3 view. My question is, how can I get a JavaScript string array from it? If you do something like:

```
var choices="@Model.Choices";
alert(choices);
alert(choices[1]);
```

The message will be "choice1choice2choice3choice4" and "undefined"

What is the syntax I need to have to have choices turn into a string array in JavaScript? For example:

```
alert(choices[0]);
alert(choices[1]);
```

Should output "choice1", and "choice2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var choices = [ '@Html.Raw(string.Join("', '", Model.Choices))' ];
```

Please note, if you have 0 items, this will fail by adding one empty item to the array. You should ensure that the choices won't have any `'` (single quotes).

Comment: Doing this didn't work. I got `choice1&#39;, &#39;choice2&#39;, &#39;choice3&#39;, &#39;choice4` when I alerted choice[0] but undefined if I tried choice[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
['@string.Join("','", Model.Choices)']
```

Comment: Doing this didn't work. I got `choice1&#39;, &#39;choice2&#39;, &#39;choice3&#39;, &#39;choice4` when I alerted choice[0] but undefined if I tried choice[1]

Comment: output un-escaped html (@Html.Raw)